# Is it ok to point an edit and create attribute route to the same action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For example. In this case the action "CreateProduct" would be referenced by both urls. If there is a productKey available then it would edit the existing product, otherwise, it would create a new product.

```
[Route("products/create")]
[Route("products/edit/{productKey}"]
public ActionResult CreateProduct(string productKey){
    if(productKey)
        edit...
    else
        create...
}
```

Comment: what does "is it ok" mean? It does probably work. Do you have any error to solve? If not, are you asking about the principle of it? As a personal note, I find this confusing. But this is personal opinion, unless you have more specific goal in mind, answers will be opinions as well.

Comment: Yeah I should have phrased that better. Is it good practice so that I avoid code duplication.

Comment: It may save you a few lines of code, but it adds complexity, and make it hard to read. As a developer, I expect a method named "Create" to create, not create _or edit_ (imagine your colleague browsing the list of methods in the dropdown of Visual Studio)  Also, I have not usually seen several routes being handled by the same controller action (but my experience is limited), another confusion source. Avoiding code duplication is good, but you can achieve that by factoring the common code to another private function if needed.

Comment: Also, there is the "user experience" of your API endpoint consumer to take into account. If the `/edit` without `productKey` actually creates a new product and act exactly like `/create`, my opinion is that it should _redirect_ to  `/create`.